# How to xdt:locator match() a node's text?

Tags: web-config, xdt-transform

I want to use the `InsertIfMissing` function with a locator of the node's `text()`.
I tried the following:

```
<SessionItem xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(text())">new_item</SessionItem>
```

But it looks like the xdt doesn't recognize the `text()` function.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible with `xdt:Locator="Condition(boolean(XPATH EXPERSSION)"`.

For example,

```
<SessionItem xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Condition(boolean(//SessionItem[text()=&quot;new_item&quot;]))">new_item</SessionItem>
```